# Friendly Url in asp.net forms

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, url-routing

I want my url in asp.net forms as 
    **http://www.somesite.com/productid** 
    instead of
     **http://www.somesite.com/product/productid** 
    using asp.net forms.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use concept called routing to achieve that task so for that you need a Global.asax file. Following is a very basic code to start with of course using same idea you can do routing for any page.

Add Global.asax file from Add > New Item > Global.asax

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace YOUR_NAMESPACE
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }

        private void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            // to avoid considering files having extension other than .aspx
            routes.Ignore("{*allaspx}", new { allaspx = @".*\.aspx(/.*)?" });
            routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.Ignore("{*allcss}",  new { allcss = @".*\.css(/.*)?" });
            routes.Ignore("{*alljpg}",  new { alljpg = @".*\.jpg(/.*)?" });
            routes.Ignore("{*allpng}",  new { allpng = @".*\.png(/.*)?" });
            routes.Ignore("{*allpdf}",  new { allpdf = @".*\.pdf(/.*)?" });
            routes.Ignore("{*alldoc}",  new { alldoc = @".*\.doc(/.*)?" });
            routes.Ignore("{*alljs}",   new { alljs = @".*\.js(/.*)?" });

            // first parameter: your route name to work within your code
            // second parameter: your friendly url is "product/{id}" you can rename it if
            // third parameter: your page name and location
            routes.MapPageRoute("Product-Detail", "product/{id}", "~/product.aspx");
        }

        protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Your RoutingHelper.cs file to get your friendly URL within code

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace YOUR_NAMESPACE
{
    public class RoutingHelpers
    {
        public static string GetProductRouteURL(int id)
        {
            var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
            return page.GetRouteUrl("Product-Detail", new { id = id });
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can use this URL any where in your project

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Project.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <title>Default</title>

</head>
<body>

    <form id="mainForm" runat="server">
        <!-- 100 is your product id -->
        Go to Product <a href="<%= RoutingHelpers.GetProductRouteURL(100) %>">Product</a>

    </form>        

</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE**

Your routeName which is in this exmple "Product-Detail" must be same in the RoutingHelper file and Global.asax file
You can name RoutingHelper class what ever you want to

Hope it helps you out

Comment: i am getting url as http://localhost:52742/product/100 but i want http://localhost:52742/100

Comment: Remove routes.MapPageRoute("Product-Detail", "product/{id}", "~/product.aspx"); product from "product/{id}"

Comment: Got It .Thank you